# Cannot GET / on Heroku Platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I've deployed my MEAN Stack App to Heroku Platform. Everything running well on Local Server, it can Reload Page, Access Page with URL. But on Live Server, Heroku, my app can't reload, access page with URL, it always return :

> Cannot GET /

When I check my browser log, returns nothing. This is my app.js file :

```
const express   = require('express');
const path      = require('path');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const passport  = require('passport');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const config    = require('./config/database');
const port      = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const cors      = require('cors');
const app       = express();
const users     = require('./routes/users');
const companies = require('./routes/companies');
const reports   = require('./routes/reports');

app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(config.database);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
    console.log('Connected to ' +config.database);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log('Unable to Connect ' +config.database);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/reports', reports);
app.use('/companies', companies);
app.use('/users', users);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('index');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server Running on Port : '+port)
});
```

[EDITED] Heroku logs added :

> »   Error: Multiple apps in git remotes  »      Usage: --remote
>   origin  »         or: --app jwti  »      Your local git repository has
>   more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.  »      Because of this, we
>   can't determine which app you want to run this command against.  »
>   Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.  »      Heroku
>   remotes in repo:  »      jwti (heroku)  »   jwti (origin)  »  »
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Comment: Is there anything in `heroku logs` ?

Comment: I've edit the post

Comment: Looks like you haven't deployed the app properly. Did you do `git push heroku master`? [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Comment: Yes I did it, how I can check it properly? Or should I create a new one?